# Leveling up and Getting Items! v2

Tags: strategy, optimization

This is follow up question to [Leveling up and Getting Items!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85030/leveling-up-and-getting-items)

> You are playing an online RPG game with 9 friends of yours (10 people
>   in total) and in the game, there is a 2-player dungeon where you level
>   up every time you enter and complete it. Only up to two players are
>   allowed inside it at a time. At the beginning of the game, everybody
>   is level 1 as usual. Before the game released, there was a beta and
>   you know how to level up fast from it, but there are some tricks you
>   discovered.
>
> - You cannot complete the dungeon alone.
> - After completing this 2-player dungeon with your friend, you and your friend will get 1 level.
> - If you play the dungeon with someone exactly one level below you, you will get an extra item at the end of the dungeon, but you cannot
>     enter the dungeon with a friend more than one level below you.
> - If you try to enter the dungeon with the same person again, no one will get any experience to level up or item.
> - You can share the items later, they are not soulbound!

There is a patch happened today! I do not want to bother you with the whole patch notes but the most important part is as below:

> - If you play the dungeon with someone <s>exactly one</s> **at most 2** levels below you, you will get an extra item at the end of the dungeon, but you cannot  enter the dungeon with a friend more than <s>one level</s> **two levels** below you.

So

> **Does this patch change anything?** we did not start to play yet, can we get more than 40 items?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It changes a lot!
>
>
>  Building off the logic of my answer to part 1, "cycles" were limited in that players could only be in them twice (excepting the weird "5-apart" cases).  With your added rule, players can be in a cycle 3 times, allowing us to do a lot more than we did before.  The first and 45th pair are still hopeless, so the answer is 43 extra items
>
>
>  [2,3] [3,4] [4,5] [5,6] [6,7] [7,8] [8,9] [9,10] [10,1]
>
>  [1,4] [4,7] [7,10] [10,3] [3,6] [6,9] [2,5] [9,2] [5,8] [8,1]
>
>  [1,3] [2,4] [3,5] [4,6] [5,7] [6,8] [7,9] [8,10] [9,1] [10,2]
>
>  [1,6] [6,2] [6,10] [10,5] [10,4] [4,9] [4,8] [8,3] [8,2] [2,7]
>
>  [1,5] [5,9] [3,9] [3,7] [7,1] [1,2]
>
>
>  That looks really confusing.  There a nicer way to do charts in here?  This is why I usually do screen captures of excel.  As for the order I chose, I didn't try too hard, it just sort of fell together at the end.  I'm sure there are many solutions at 43.

Comment: You've omitted pair [4,9]

Comment: Copy error, my bad.  Thanks for checking!

Comment: I'm not quite convinced 45th pair is still hopeless, shouldn't it be possible to set them to have one or two levels difference now?

Comment: Oh!  So when you generate every unique pairing, there's 45 of them.  Each player occurs 9 times among all pairs so the 45th pairing must be two level 8's going into the dungeon.  Can't be helped.